# How to create a shared DataSet programmatically in Report Server 2008 using Report Server Web Service?

Tags: dataset, ssrs-2008, report

I would like to know how to create a shared DataSet programmatically in Report Server using the report server web service?

I can create folders (using CreateFolder method), reports (CreateReport), data sources, but the web service doesn't have a method to create a DataSet.

example creating a report:

```
ReportingService2005 rs = new ReportingService2005();
rs.Credentials  = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(folderPath, fileInfo.Name));
byte[] bytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
int x = fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

string reportName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.Name);
rs.CreateReport(reportName, "/reports", true, bytes, null);
```

thanks in advance
fc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem.

The problem was that I was using the 2005 wsdl specification. We should use the 2010 spec, wich allows to create datasets using CreateCatalogItem.

http://localhost/ReportServer_XXX/reportservice2010.asmx?wsdl

ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
...
rs.CreateCatalogItem("DataSet", reportName, "/DataSets", true, bytes, null, out warnings);

reference:
ReportingService2010 Methods

Comment: How did you set the data source that the DataSet uses?